# Neo4J store size increases after major delete operation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4J in Docker. Despite doing a major delete operation, the store size of the graph seems to increase.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me why this is. Thanks!

Comment: How do you perform the delete? The 'cypher' tag suggests you use Cypher, is that correct?

Comment: So I was trying to delete all unconnected nodes. So this is what I used:
`MATCH (n) WHERE size((n)--())=0
DETACH DELETE n;`

Comment: How do you calcul the store size ? Are you taking in count the transaction logs ?

Answer (score 1):

It comes from how Neo4j store data.

There is a node store (ie a file) and every node takes a fixed size. So when you delete a node, the corresponding record in the file is cleaned, but the file still has the same size.

After some times, Neo4j can reused this node's id to avoid to have a big 'empty' file.

So it's normal that your datastore size don't dicreased.

Moreover, everytime you perform an action on a data (create, update or delete), the modification is saved into the transaction logs.

And that's why your datastore size  increases.

There is a policy for this log retention that you can configure, and the default one is to keep all the transaction of the last X days (I don't remember the number).
Cheers

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean the increase in size is only due to the transaction logs?

Comment: In your case, yes I think. You can check it by doing the same thing, but don't take care of the `neostore.transaction.X` files when you calculate the store size